# requests_html render() throwing OSError: [WinError 14001]

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests-html

Hello I'm trying to do web scraping with the python module requests-html to handle dynamic content on the page https://www.monster.com/jobs/search?q=Software+Engineer&where=. My code is:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = 'https://www.monster.com/jobs/search?q=Software+Engineer&where='
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get(url)
response.html.render()
```

but when I run response.html.render() I get this error

```
OSError: [WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail
```

The first time I ran render() I got

```
[W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] start chromium download.
Download may take a few minutes.
[W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader]
chromium download done.
[W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] chromium extracted to: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\588429
```

however the file path doesn't exist but pyppeteer is actually an installed package (pyppeteer==0.2.5). Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You're having this issue because chromium setup failed.

You can either try to reinstall request_html or what I did was switching from the python from the Windows store to the download from the python website and then installing request_html again.

After having everything setup correctly with the downloaded python I switched back to python 3.9 from the store and everything is still working.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution might be to copy the contents of your Chrome install

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
```

into a directory the request_html library is looking for

```
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\<version number>\chrome-win
```

Be sure to check the version number that requests_html is looking for.  It was 1181205 in my case, which I found by looking at the chromium_downloader.py and launcher.py files of the pyppeteer library. I had to manually create the version number directory, as Pyppeteer didn't do it for me.