# Requests_html render() returning WinError 14001 on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-requests, chromium, python-requests-html

I'm working on a web scraping project using Python. I'm using the requests_html library. My problem is identical to [one that someone else had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897511/requests-html-render-throwing-oserror-winerror-14001) . When I run

`r.html.render()`

I get an error that says

```
OSError: [WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail`.
```

On the other thread I linked, someone said that the issue is with chromium and that I should reinstall requests & Python. I did a reinstallation of Python (both from VSCode and from the Python website) as well as reinstalling requests. However, I am still receiving this error when trying to run my code. Does anyone have any advice on what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after initially installing python via the Microsoft App store. I uninstalled that instance of python and reinstalled it using an installer from python.org and that resolved the error. There was one error on the very first run of my code when the initial chromium download was triggered by the call to `render()` but after that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to command prompt as admin and run sxstrace.exe.

```
sxstrace.exe Trace -logfile:tracefile.etl
```

run your program until error occurs then go to the cmd window and press Enter key.
Then run

```
sxstrace.exe Parse -logfile:tracefile.etl -outfile:tracefile.txt
```

this will output a file into your System32 directory. Find it and post contents of the .txt file here. It should contain information on what is wrong.